# Updating Duplicate Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to remove the duplicate values in python dictionary.

We have a snippet like below,

I want to make use of "Number" Key and remove the duplicates by updating them.

```
[
{
'Message': 'Fetched',
'Code': '200',
'Number': '20290775'
}, 
{
'Message': 'Fetched',
'Code': '202',
'Number': '20290776'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290775'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290776'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290777'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290778'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20556729'
}
```

]

How can we  generate into below snippet

```
[ 
{
'Message': 'Fetched',
'Code': '200',
'Number': '20290775'
}, 
{
'Message': 'Fetched',
'Code': '200',
'Number': '20290776'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290777'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20290778'
}, 
{
'Message': '',
'Code': '',
'Number': '20556729'
}
```

]

Is it Possible to generate and remove the duplicate dictionary values?

Comment: Why not make this a dictionary keyed on `Number` rather than a list?  The simplest path toward removing the duplicates involves building such a dictionary as an intermediate step -- if you have the option of just making it a dictionary in the first place, the entire problem goes away!

Comment: Of course it's _possible_.  How do you decide which version to keep when the keys match but not the other entries, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I  want to compare two dictionaries when there is a "Number" Match and make it a single dictionary. @DavisHerring

Comment: If you can use Pandas: `pd.DataFrame(lst).sort_values(['Number', 'Code', 'Message']).drop_duplicates('Number', keep='last')`

Comment: I tried multiple ways of implementing  it. 
But was not able to. I understand the rules and regulations of SO. After trying out several hours, I have posted the question over here. I understand that I shouldn't be asking the question over here.  @PranavHosangadi

Comment: You _should_ ask here, we love that you're asking, but please show us what you tried and ask a question about your attempt. I'm sure you got _somewhere_ in your attempt, so include a [mre] of your best one, identify how it fell short of your expectations, and ask how to fix it! That way you'll learn because you'll understand what you did wrong, and usually people will still post completely different approaches if there's a better way to get to where you want. Just asking how to get what you want from your input sounds like you want us to do it for you, and that's not nice

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to remove duplicates based on number:

```
result = []
for item in input_list:
    for element in result:
        if item["Number"] == element["Number"]:
            break
    else:
        result.append(item)
print(result)
```

For your example, this will output:

```
[{'Message': 'Fetched', 'Code': '200', 'Number': '20290775'}, {'Message': 'Fetched', 'Code': '202', 'Number': '20290776'}, {'Message': '', 'Code': '', 'Number': '20290777'}, {'Message': '', 'Code': '', 'Number': '20290778'}, {'Message': '', 'Code': '', 'Number': '20556729'}]
```

Comment: The `if not result:` is superfluous: the loop would already exit immediately (and run its `else:`).

Comment: You are right, I have updated the code

Answer (score -1):

mylist = [ value for value in { value['number']:value for value in mylist }.values() ]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To clarify the comment above, consider adding an explanation as it would greatly improve the quality of your answer for OP and future readers